# React Native : Is it is good to use UI kit for design purpose?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I'm starting a new react native app.So what would be the best way for doing the UI? I tried a ui-kit but it seems to be more complicated than building from scratch. So please guide me for an efficient way.But I think it will not take much time for building the app using an ui-kit right?I am confused please guide me.

Comment: Customising React Native styling isn’t the most easiest thing. Many apps demand custom styling, which makes component kits not too useful. In addition, it is challenging to customise each and every component, as the flexibility that you gain with traditional CSS on the web doesn’t carry over easily to component libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You don’t need a UI Kit if you code UI on your own! It is actually
>   good to code your own UI because you have complete control over the
>   code.
>
> UI kits do help a lot by reducing the development time but sometimes
>   you might need more customisation than a UI kit offers! So It is
>   always good to code your own UI coupled with smaller component
>   libraries.

Here are some of tool kits that are available and actively maintained by the community itself. These tool kits will not only save up your tons of development time but also help you to provide consistent design over different devices.

- NativeBase
- React Native Material Kit
- Shoutem UI
- React Native Elements
- React Native UI Kitten
- Nachos UI
- React Native Gifted Chat

> **If none of these choices float your boat, you can always learn how to style components from scratch yourself.**